# For a file pointer in C, how to measure the distance between the current position to the end of file?

Tags: c, file, position, eof, file-pointer

For a given file pointer (`FILE *`), is it possible to rapidly determine the distance from current position to the end of file.

The time it takes to figure out the actual distance should be not dependent to the distance.

For example the subtraction of `fpos_t`, but fpos_t is not integer, it cannot be operated numerically. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: Take a look at [fseek()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm)

Comment: There may not be any predetermined end of file nor size...

Comment: The _distance_ to the end of the file is not as linear as one may hope.  @Audra Jacot, how do you want to use the _distance_?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you *first open* the file, you can use [`fseek()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) to go to the end of the file (but see the note below), then use `ftell()` to get the position and save this (as the file's size). Then call `rewind()` to go back to the beginning.

Then, the return value from any later call to [`ftell()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/ftell/) can be subtracted from your saved 'size' to get the offset (distance) from the current position to the file's end:

```c
// Given a FILE* fp that's just been opened:
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long int endpos = ftell(fp);
rewind(fp); // Or you can use fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
//...
// Later in your code:
long int dtoend = endpos - ftell(pf);
```

But note that implementations are *not required* to implement `SEEK_END`: from the cplusplus.com page on `fseek` linked above:

> - Library implementations are allowed to not meaningfully support SEEK_END (therefore, code using it has no real standard portability).

Just to clarify (following on from some comments): The code above *requires* that the `endpos` value be saved for the duration of the file's open/read operations. One *could* avoid this by seeking to the end and then restoring the *current* position at any point, but that would be far less efficient. For example, one could write a function to get the distance-to-end at any time:

```c
long int dtoend(FILE *fp)
{
    long int curpos = ftell(fp); // Get current position
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);      // Go to the file's end
    long endpos = ftell(fp);     // Gets the file's size
    fseek(fp, curpos, SEEK_SET); // Restore previous pos
    return endpos - curpos;      // Return the distance!
}
```

---

**Note for use with large (> 2GB) files:** The above code uses standard `fseek` and `ftell` functions that use the `long int` type (which is often 32-bits wide) for file positions; to use similar code for larger files, there are a number of (albeit platform-specific) alternatives...

On Windows platforms, using the `MSVC` (or compatible) compilers, there are the [`_ftelli64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ftell-ftelli64?view=vs-2019) and [`_fseeki64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fseek-fseeki64?view=vs-2019) functions, which can be used in virtually the same way as their 'standard' counterparts; for example, by making the following changes to the above code:

```c
//...
    int64_t curpos = _ftelli64(fp); // Get current position
    _fseeki64(fp, 0LL, SEEK_END);   // Go to the file's end
    //... and similar changes elsewhere
```

On Linux systems, the 64-bit calls are implemented as [`ftello` and `fseeko`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/ftello) if you ***make sure*** to `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64`.

Other platforms/compilers may implement either (or both) of the above, or have some other, very similar 64-bit replacements.

---

**Note #2 - Error Handling:** As pointed out in the comments, calling `fseek` with `SEEK_END` as the *origin* argument can fail in number of different circumstances; for example, if the file pointer is `stdin`, if it refers to a pipe stream, or (on some systems) if the file is opened in **text mode**<sup>†</sup>. To handle such cases, one should really check the return value of the `fseek` call, which will be *non-zero* if it failed. So, here is a 64-bit version of the `dtoend` function with such error handling implemented (note for compilers other than `MSVC` or `GNU`, you will need to add the relevant definition macros for the `bigseek` and `bigtell` functions):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#if defined (_MSC_VER) // MSVC/Windows...
    #define bigtell _ftelli64
    #define bigseek _fseeki64
#elif defined (__GNUC__) // GNU/Linux...
    #define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
    #define bigtell ftello
    #define bigseek fseeko
//
// Feel free to add other compiler/platform implementations
//

#else // Unknown platform/compiler - likely to cause warnings!
    #define bigtell ftell
    #define bigseek fseek 
#endif

int64_t dtoend(FILE* fp)
{
    int64_t curpos = bigtell(fp);                   // Saves the file's current position
    if (bigseek(fp, 0LL, SEEK_END) != 0) return -1; // -1 can ONLY be an error condition
    int64_t endpos = bigtell(fp);                   // Retrieve file size (end position)
    bigseek(fp, curpos, SEEK_SET);                  // Restore previously saved position
    return endpos - curpos;                         // Subtract to get distance from end
}
```

<sup>†</sup> From the same [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fseek/) page linked above:

> For streams open in text mode, offset shall either be zero or a value
>   returned by a previous call to ftell, and origin shall necessarily be
>   SEEK_SET. If the function is called with other values for these
>   arguments, support depends on the particular system and library
>   implementation (non-portable).

Comment: I would note that there is no system in wide use that does not implement `SEEK_END`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne Actually, your comment was vey helpful - see edited answer - I've also corrected the argument order in the `fseek` calls!

Comment: `long int endptr` calling an integer a ptr ... is well ... at least confusing.

Comment: File sizes could exceed `LONG_MAX`, especially when `long` is 32-bit.  Hence an advantage to `fpos_t`.  Of course one can't subtract them.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for pointing that out - see latest edit.

Comment: You may also explain that some *files* have no size/end-of, eg pipes, /dev/null, etc.

Comment: `int64_t` should be good enough for file size until maybe 2050.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Thanks for pointing this out - see latest edit.

Comment: The MSVC version is terribly unportable. It will only work on Windows, nothing more.

Comment: Surely there has to be a POSIX way of doing this... I think you can do it with file descriptors, but not with `FILE`. That's a pain.

Comment: @S.S.Anne There may very well be other methods, but the one I have given will work on many compilers/platforms, and will satisfy OP's requirement for 'rapidly' if properly coded. Also, I've changed the last piece of code to be a *wee* bit more portable!

Comment: I would very much like to thank the commentators (S.S.Anne, chux and Jean-Baptiste) for their suggestions! These have enabled the 'evolution' of my original answer into one that likely has much wider relevance.

Answer (score 3):

> For example the subtraction of fpos_t, but fpos_t is not integer, it cannot be operated numerically. Is there any alternative way?

No, you can't.

The FILE structure doesn't know how long the file is, and therefore has no easy way to find this distance. The file is treated like a road - you turn into the road, and drive along, and when the road ends, you'll find out. But there are no signs telling you how much longer the road is.

You could ask the OS separately, with `stat` or similar. But note that FILE does not even always refer to a file with a defined end - it could be `stdin` coming from a pipe, and the size completely unknown at the time.

Comment: "No, you can't." is more like "No, you can't always" as .`fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END)` does work on many `FILE`.  Exceptions include: "Setting the file position indicator to end-of-file, as with fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END), has undefined behavior for a binary stream (because of possible trailing null characters) or for any stream with state-dependent encoding that does not
assuredly end in the initial shift state."

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that is not _fast_, as it simply reads the whole file to find its end. I understood the OP's question as looking for a way to abbreviate reading a complete file just to find it's end.

Comment: "it simply reads the whole file to find its end" --> that may happen, yet C does not specify that behavior.  That is an implementation detail.  For streams with known size, the underlying code could simple use `SEEK_END` to indicate a look-up in stream meta- data and return the size.