# Fastest way to get char* from file in C

Tags: arrays, c, file, optimization

I have function which gets arguments: `char* filedata` (stores whole file) and `FILE *fp` (the opened file).

```c
void read_file(char *filedata, FILE *fp){
  char buffer[1000];

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))
  {
    char *new_str;
    if((new_str = malloc(strlen(filedata) + strlen(buffer)+1)) != NULL)
    {
      new_str[0] = '\0'; // ensures the memory is an empty string
      strcat(new_str, filedata);
      strcat(new_str, buffer);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("malloc failed!\n");
    }
    strcpy(filedata, new_str);
  }

  fclose(fp);
}
```

But this isn't too fast... is there faster way to read the whole file?

Comment: You want to read all lines not just a simple read. please edit title if true.

Comment: "Fast" is not well defined. Fast to open a file? Fast to access the data in the file? What is fast enough? What are the requirements?

Comment: Looks very leaky to me:(

Comment: The answer to your question: Yes. That said, beyond the amazing memory leaks, I don't suppose you've ever heard of  [Shlemiel, The Painter](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/). And fyi, whoever wrote the spec for your function, they took a page from everything wrong with `gets` and manifested it in a file-read operation. E.g., a pointer for target data without any reference to how much space is actually there. That's a recipe for doom. It also makes all the rest of this pointless. Just keep dumping data into that target, advancing `filedata` as you go. Then... *don't*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some caveats, you can read the entire file into an appropriately-sized buffer in one fell swoop using the [`fread()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

The following code outlines how to open the file, determine its size, allocate a buffer of that size, then read the file's data (all of it) into that buffer. But note the caveats about the `fseek` and `ftell` functions (discussed afterwards):

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char* filename = "MyFile.txt"; // Or whatever
    FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "rb"); // Open in binary mode
    int seek = fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); // CAVEAT: Files in BINARY mode may not support SEEK_END ...
    if (seek != 0) {
        printf("Cannot fseek on binary file!\n");
        fclose(fp);
        return 1;
    }
    size_t filesize = (size_t)ftell(fp); // ... but this is not reliable if opened in TEXT mode!
    char* filedata = calloc(filesize + 1, 1); // Add 1 for the terminating "nul" character
    rewind(fp);
    fread(filedata, 1, filesize, fp); // Read whole file
    
    // Clean up ...
    fclose(fp);
    free(filedata);

    return 0;
}
```

**Caveats:**

Note that files opened in BINARY mode (as in the `"rb"` mode argument I gave in the `fopen()` call) are not **required** to support the `SEEK_END` origin in calls to `fseek()`; if this is the case on your platform, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/238609/10871073) offers some alternatives to determine the file's size. [From cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek):

> … Binary streams are not required to support SEEK_END, in
> particular if additional null bytes are output.

However, on the other hand, opening the file in TEXT mode (using `"rt"`) will make the call to `ftell` effectively meaningless, in terms of the required size for your input buffer and the value specified to `fread`; [from cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell):

> If the stream is open in text mode, the value returned by this
> function is unspecified and is only meaningful as the input to
> fseek().

Also note that, as pointed out in the comments, the `fseek()` and `ftell()` functions will fail if the size of the file is larger than the maximum value that can be stored in a `long int` variable; to handle such cases, you can use the (platform-dependent) 64-bit equivalents, as I described in [an answer I posted some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61272348/10871073).

Comment: Also, `int seek = fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);` will have problems for files too large for the size to be contained in an `int`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, indeed. But the 64-bit versions of `fseek` and `ftell` are not (yet?) standardized across platforms/compilers. (Actually, it would be the `ftell` that causes the problem - the `fseek` function call wouldn't need/use the over-sized integer.)

Comment: @AndrewHenle Also note that `fseek` and `ftell` use **long int** offsets/sizes. But I added a note linking to the platform-specific ways of handling BIG files.

Comment: True, but `long` is only 4 bytes on Windows systems, even 64-bit ones.

Answer (score 2):

Below's my function illustrating how I usually do it. Not sure how fast it is compared to all other possible C implementations. But I'd imagine they're all pretty similar unless poorly programmed in one way or another, which might lead to slower, less efficient execution.

```
/* ==========================================================================
 * Function:    readfile ( FILE *ptr, int *nbytes )
 * Purpose:     read open file ptr into internal buffer
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Arguments:   ptr (I)         FILE * to already open (via fopen)
 *                              file, whose contents are to be read
 *              nbytes (O)      int * returning #bytes in returned buffer
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Returns:     ( unsigned char * )  buffer with ptr's contents
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Notes:     o caller should free() returned output buffer ptr when finished
 * ======================================================================= */
/* --- entry point --- */
unsigned char *readfile ( FILE *ptr, int *nbytes ) {
  /* --- 
   * allocations and declarations
   * ------------------------------- */
  unsigned char *outbuff = NULL;        /* malloc'ed and realloc'ed below */
  int  allocsz=0, reallocsz=500000,     /*total #bytes allocated, #realloc */
       blksz=9900, nread=0,             /* #bytes to read, #actually read */
       buffsz = 0;                      /* total #bytes in buffer */
  /* ---
   * collect all bytes from ptr
   * ----------------------------- */
   if ( ptr != NULL ) {                 /* return NULL error if no input */
    while ( 1 ) {                       /* read all input from file */
      if ( buffsz+blksz + 99 >= allocsz ) { /* first realloc more memory */
        allocsz += reallocsz;           /*add reallocsz to current allocation*/
        if ( (outbuff=realloc(outbuff,allocsz)) == NULL ) /* reallocate */
          goto end_of_job; }            /* quit with NULL ptr if failed */
      nread = fread(outbuff+buffsz,1,blksz,ptr); /* read next block */
      if ( nread < 1 ) break;           /* all done, nothing left to read */
      buffsz += nread;                  /* add #bytes from current block */
      } /* --- end-of-while(1) --- */
    fclose(ptr);                        /* close fopen()'ed file ptr */
    } /* --- end-of-if(ptr!=NULL) --- */
  end_of_job:
    if ( nbytes != NULL ) *nbytes = buffsz; /* #bytes in outbuff */
    return ( outbuff );                 /* back to caller with output or NULL*/
  } /* --- end-of-function readfile() --- */
```

Comment: Why do you not allocate the entire file size to begin with?

Comment: @einpoklum The function's often reading output from popen("command","r") rather than a file, and my actual function contains a third arg _int isclose_ which leaves ptr open if 0, fclose's if 1, and pclose's if 2. So I could only know the entire size for an fopen'ed ptr, not a popen'ed one.

Answer (score 1):

Annotating your function (not mentioning the leaks, etc) and counting the operations on the character buffers:

---

```
void read_file(char *filedata, FILE *fp){
  char buffer[1000];

  while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp))      // <<-- NEW_SIZE
  {
    char *new_str;
    if((new_str = malloc(strlen(filedata)       // <<-- OLD_SIZE
         + strlen(buffer)                       // <<-- NEW_SIZE
        +1)) != NULL)
    {
      new_str[0] = '\0'; // ensures the memory is an empty string
      strcat(new_str, filedata);                // <<-- OLD_SIZE
      strcat(new_str, buffer);                  // <<-- OLD_SIZE + NEW_SIZE
    }
    else
    {
      printf("malloc failed!\n");
    }
    strcpy(filedata, new_str);                  // <<-- OLD_SIZE + NEW_SIZE
  }

  fclose(fp);
}
```

---

`fgets()`. `strlen()`, `strcat()` and `strcpy()` all need to loop over a character buffer.
Only the `fgets()` is actually needed, the rest of the copying can be avoided.

Adding the number of passes over the buffers:

sum of operations per loop: 4 * OLD_SIZE + 4 * NEW_SIZE
and: keep in mind that OLD_SIZE is actually SUM(NEW_SIZE), recursively, so your function has
**QUADRATIC behavior** wrt the number of times the loop iterates.(basically the number of lines read)

So you end up with:

```
Number of times a character is inspected
    = 4 * N_LINE * LINE_SIZE
    + 8 * (NLINE * (NLINE-1) ) * LINE_SIZE
    ;
```

, which implies that for a 100 line file you need about 40K passes over the string(s).

[this is the "Schlemiel, the painter" story]